# Comparing two times in javascript

Tags: javascript, time

I need to run a specific logic if current time for the following cases

1. less than 7 am
2. between 7am and 9 am
3. between 9am and 7pm
4. greater than 7pm

I am finding it difficult see how I can see if the current time is between an interval:

```
if(currentHour < 7){
    console.log("Time is before than 7 am :" + 0 );
}
else if (currentHour > 19){
    console.log("Time is after than 7 pm :" + 12148 );
}
else if(//Compare between the hours)
```

Please help with appropriate code.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (currentHour >= 7 && currentHour <=19) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were dealing with a single interval, you could use the [logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) (`&&`) like this:

```
if(currentHour >= 7 && currentHour <= 9) {...}
```

Since you're dealing with multiple contiguous intervals, you can simplify the logic with `else` statements, because they won't run if the previous `if` condition is true:

```
if(currentHour < 7) { //less than 7am
}
else if(currentHour <= 9) { //between 7am and 9am
}
else if(currentHour <= 19) { //between 9am and 7pm
}
else { //greater than 7pm
}
```

(You may need to change `<` or `<=` depending on whether you want an *inclusive* or *exclusive* between.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code. The `getHours()` method of the `Date` class returns the current hour in  24 hours format. ( `4 PM` is `16` , `7 PM` is `19` , etc... )

```
var currentHour = new Date().getHours();

if (currentHour < 7) {
   console.log("less than 7 am");
}

if (currentHour >= 7 && currentHour <=9) {
   console.log("between 7am and 9 am");
}

if (currentHour >= 9 && currentHour <= 19) {
   console.log("between 9am and 7pm");
}

if (currentHour > 19) {
   console.log("greater than 7pm");
}
```